# How to Retrieve Specific User Roles (Permission Levels) from SharePoint Site Using Client Object Model?

Tags: user, roles

I'm trying to get user names from List and for those user roles i need to Retrieve from Site using CSOM. Please help 
me if any one have idea i have written the below code

```
RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignment = currentweb.RoleAssignments;
```

> not initializing..

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(URL))
            {
                currentweb= context.Web; 
                try
                {

                    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Team & Contacts");
                    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                    query.ViewXml = "<View>"
                         + "<Query>"
                         + "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Team' /><Value Type='Choice'>Core Team</Value></Eq></Where>"
                         + "</Query>"
                         + "</View>";

                    ListItemCollection itemsContacts = list.GetItems(query);

                    context.Load(list);
                    context.Load(itemsContacts);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                    DataTable dtContacts = new DataTable();
                    DataTable dtdistinct = new DataTable();
                    dtContacts.Columns.Add("Employee Name");
                    dtContacts.Columns.Add("Login Name");
                    dtContacts.Columns.Add("Team");
foreach (ListItem item in itemsContacts)
                    {
                        context.Load(item);

                        FieldUserValue singleValue = (FieldUserValue)item["Employee_x0020_Name"];
                        User user = context.Web.EnsureUser(singleValue.LookupValue);
                        context.Load(user);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();

                        string userName = singleValue.LookupValue.ToString();

                        userName = user.LoginName;

RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignment = currentweb.RoleAssignments; 
                        for (int i = roleAssignment.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            RoleAssignment roleAssignmentSingle = roleAssignment[i];
                            System.Type t = roleAssignmentSingle.Member.GetType();
                            //Principal signleUser = (Principal)userName;
                            if (t.Name == userName)
                            {

                            }

                        }
 dtContacts.Rows.Add(userName, item["Role"], item["Team"]);

                    }  
                    dtgvContacts.DataSource = dtContacts;
                } 

                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because web has not been loaded. Load the web i.e. `context.Load(currentweb);`. Finally Load the `RoleAssignmentCollection` and then execute query before looping through them. Example:

```
RoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignment = currentweb.RoleAssignments; 
context.Load(roleAssignment);
context.ExecuteQuery();
for (int i = roleAssignment.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: Hi Role assignment collection loading I need to get Roles for specific user . please help me how can I get RoRoles for specific User